# Boundaries after change of variable in integral : is there a general technique to find them?

Tags: integration

Consider the following (example) integral :

$$ I = \int_{t}^{t+\Delta t} dt_1 \int_{t}^{t_1} dt_2 f(t_1,t_2) $$

It is equal to :

$$ I = \int_{0}^{\Delta t} d \tau \int_{t+\tau}^{t + \Delta t} dt_1 f(t_1,\tau)  $$

To see it, we can draw the region on a paper and look at the boundaries $\tau$ and $t_1$ have to respect after the change of variable

My question is the following :

Is there a straightforward technique / a theorem to directly apply to find the boundaries ?

Because here, to find the boundaries, I drawed the region on a paper and tried to think what would be the boundaries of $t_1$ once $\tau$ is fixed (which mean : trying to represent a fixed $\tau$ condition).

So I wonder if there is a "brute-force" method that exists for such problem. Because if the region had been more complicated I couldn't probably have found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you want to do is take it one step at a time. You've combined two steps: Substituting $\tau = t_2 - t$ for $t_2$, and then exchanging the order of integration (which is not always justifiable, but I'll assume $f$ is nice enough that it works here). Treat these steps separately.

Just the substitution is easy: When $t_2 = t, \tau = 0$ and when $t_2 = t_1, \tau = t_1 - t$. So we get 
$$I = \int_{t}^{t+\Delta t} dt_1 \int_0^{t_1 - t} d\tau f(t_1,\tau + t)$$

Note that it is $f(t_1, \tau + t)$ being integrated, not $f(t_1, \tau)$ as you have in your final integral - changing the order of integration will not affect this. You final form is just incorrect.

Now, to change the order of integration of two variables (again, assuming that $f$ is nice enough to justify it), you start off with some expression of the form
$$\int_a^bdx\int_{l(x)}^{u(x)}dy\,f(x,y)$$ with $l(x) \le u(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and want to change it to
$$\int_c^ddy\int_{L(y)}^{U(y)}dx\,f(x,y)$$
Unfortunately, this is not always possible. For example $$\int_0^{4\pi} dx\int_{\cos x}^{2-\cos x}dy$$
is over this region:
[image]

If we attempt to integrate over $y$ first, for $y \ne 1, x$ does not vary over a contiguous range. So instead of a nice single integral, we end up having to break it into multiple integrals over different subsets of the range.

The general practice is:

- $c$ is the lowest value of $l(x)$ for $x\in[a,b]$.
- $d$ is the highest value of $u(x)$ for $x\in[a,b]$
- solve the inequalities $l(x) \le y$ and $y \le u(x)$ for $x$. The solution may be several disjoint intervals.

Applying that the cosines example:

- The minimum of $\cos x$ on $[0,4\pi]$ is -1.
- The maximum of $2 - \cos x$ on $[0,4\pi]$ is 3.
- To solve $\cos x \le y$, we have to break $\cos x$ up into intervals where it is invertible. These are

  - $[0,\pi)$, where it is decreasing, $\cos^{-1} y \le x$.
  - $[\pi,2\pi)$, where it is increasing, $x \le 2\pi - \cos^{-1} y$
  - $[2\pi,3\pi)$, where it is decreasing, $2\pi + \cos^{-1} y \le x$
  - $[3\pi,4\pi]$, where it is increasing, $x \le 4\pi - \cos^{-1} y$

Similar results hold when you try to solve $y \le 2 - \cos x$. By putting it all together, we find

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{4\pi} dx\int_{\cos x}^{2-\cos x}dy = &\int_{-1}^1dy\left(\int_{\cos^{-1} y}^{2\pi - \cos^{-1} y} dx + \int_{2\pi+\cos^{-1} y}^{4\pi - \cos^{-1} y} dx\right)\\&+\int_{1}^3dy\left(\int_{\cos^{-1} (2-y)}^{2\pi - \cos^{-1} (2-y)} dx + \int_{2\pi+\cos^{-1} (2-y)}^{4\pi - \cos^{-1} (2-y)} dx\right)\end{align}$$

It should be obvious that graphing the region is crucial. It would be much more difficult to figure out the boundaries without a graph.

---

Your triangular boundaries are not so bad:

- The minimum of $0$ is just $0$.
- The maximum of $t_1 - t$ on $[t,t + \Delta t]$ is just $\Delta t$.
- $0 \le \tau$ puts no restrictions on $t_1$.
- $\tau \le t_1 - t$ solves to $\tau + t \le t_1$.

So the minimum value of $t_1$ is $\tau + t$, but the maximum value remains the original limit of $t + \Delta t$. Thus
$$I = \int_0^{\Delta t} d\tau \int_{\tau + t}^{t + \Delta t}dt_1\,f(t_1, \tau + t)$$